# CDN for Bootstrap 4 with Flexbox?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there a CDN that provides the Bootstrap 4 Alpha with Flexbox enabled? I found https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/alpha/, however, it looks like it has Flexbox disabled.

**EDIT:** Bootstrap 4 has been officially released since, flexbox is enabled by default. So just obtain Bootstrap via the official CDNs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/alpha/ - without

I use https://cask.scotch.io/bootstrap-4.0-flex.css - with flex enabled

Comment: But the current release is 4.0.0-alpha.4 so I wonder if scotch.io is the latest.

Comment: last-modified:Mon, 24 Aug 2015 21:06:22 GMT

Comment: See my answer below. GetBoostrap.com leads you to the latest version(s) and update information.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it is available here:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css

Comment: Yeah, thanks, in the meantime, it looks like there is a general release.

Comment: Is there an official link for that with a checksum?

Comment: I've not found anything official, but it looks like you can see the SRI in their github repo: https://github.com/MaxCDN/bootstrap-cdn/blob/develop/config/_config.yml#L237

Comment: Note - it doesn't seem to be the flex version. Perhaps post an issue

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GetBootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) website, Bootstrap 4 implements flexbox by default! Doing so however means dropping support for IE9. The CDN's for the CSS and the JS files are given on [GetBootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/) as well.